# Comparing java.sql.timestamp values

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, timestamp

for `Timestamp` values, how to compare the <= or >=, as we can use the existing

```
myTs.before(someTs)
```

But this internally checks `<` not `<=`

I need to check basically
`myTs <= someTs1 and myTs>=someTs1`

How do we compare <= or >= and also how do we get the epoch seconds from timestamp ?

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Timestamp`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `Instant` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: There is one nanosecond — one billionth of a second — where `<` and `<=` will give different results. For what purpose do you need such extreme precision?

Answer (score 2):

The [compareTo()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#compareTo-java.sql.Timestamp-) method of Timestamp class returns :

- Integer value 0 if this Timestamp object is equal to given Timestamp
- A value less than 0 if this Timestamp object is before the
  given argument
- A value greater than 0 if this Timestamp object is
  after the given argument

  ```
  ts1.compareTo(ts2) >= 0
  ```

Answer (score 0):

If it does not checks equality, you can use not of after. So:

```
!myTs.after(someTs)
```

Or, you can get time of timestamp and compare.

```
myTs.getTime() >= someTs.getTime()
```

Comment: is the getTime() returns in seconds

Comment: @supernatural , you are not right. The getTime method returns, the number of miliseconds since January 1, 1970 00:00:00 GMT. You can check the javadoc of tihs metod.

Comment: okay, so just going msTs.getTime()/1000 will give us in seconds

Answer (score 0):

You can use the negation operator (`!`) with `.before` and `.after` as shown below:

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(2021, 0, 10);// 10-Jan-2021
        Date datePast = calendar.getTime();
        Timestamp tsPast = new Timestamp(datePast.getTime());

        Date dateNow = new Date();
        Timestamp tsNow = new Timestamp(dateNow.getTime());

        // Check <=
        if (!tsNow.after(tsPast)) {
            System.out.println("Now or before");
        } else {
            System.out.println("After");
        }

        // Check >=
        if (!tsNow.before(tsPast)) {
            System.out.println("Now or after");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Before");
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
After
Now or after
```

The date-time API of `java.util` and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html).Since `java.sql.Timestamp` extends `java.util.Date`, it inherits the same problem. For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7.

You can use [`Timestamp#toInstant()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#toInstant--) to switch to the modern date-time API. Once you have `Instant`, you can convert it into other `java.time` types.

**Demo:**

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(2021, 0, 10);// 10-Jan-2021
        Date datePast = calendar.getTime();
        Timestamp tsPast = new Timestamp(datePast.getTime());
        ZonedDateTime zdtPast = tsPast.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/London"));

        Date dateNow = new Date();
        Timestamp tsNow = new Timestamp(dateNow.getTime());
        ZonedDateTime zdtNow = tsNow.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/London"));

        // Check <=
        if (!zdtNow.isAfter(zdtPast.minusMinutes(5))) {
            System.out.println("Now or before");
        } else {
            System.out.println("After");
        }

        // Check >=
        if (!zdtNow.isBefore(zdtPast)) {
            System.out.println("Now or after");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Before");
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
After
Now or after
```

### An important note:

The two timestamps can differ (i.e. can be before or after) even by the fraction of a second. However, for most practical scenarios, this is not what we want e.g. a business requirement can state that if the past date-time is less than 5 minutes of the current date-time, the processing should be done this way or that way. The modern date-time API makes it quite easier to add/subtract a time unit e.g. you can do something like:

```
if (!zdtNow.isAfter(zdtPast.minusMinutes(5))) {
    //...
} else {
    //...
}
```

Learn more about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.